# Auto approve an user after registration (Services)

Tags: users, services

Is there some way to auto approve an user after registration? I don't want to send any email confirming the email or changing the password.

I'm trying to build a register/login for an app with REST services, but I don't want the user have to check the email to change the password, I want the user can use immediately the password it just filled in the registration.

I tried adding this line in settings.php $conf['user_mail_register_no_approval_required_notify'] = FALSE; but the user continues as (not verified).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jose - Make sure you have "Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account" unchecked in your Drupal admin under /admin/config/people/accounts

Also, there seems to be a bug in the services module that doesn't set the password correctly if you send it through the REST service. If you apply this patch, you should be able to set the password and the user should be able to log in right away.

https://drupal.org/files/issues/user_create-2198005-1.patch

Comment: Thank you very much! I spent a lot of time trying to solve this issue.